# QR codes and crypto wallets

Tags: blockchain, qr-code, wallet

I'd like to make the following questions:

- If you provide a value and a wallet/smart contract address in a QR-code, it'll automatically redirect to a app to deal with such info?
- There are any standards for such a context?
- and which opensource wallet would one recommend for such experiment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a QR code with any value, for example just a 34 character BTC Wallet: `3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa` if you want to make the QR make some actions on a phone you should read about URI Schemes, for example.

`Default phone app = tel:<number>`

`Default email app = mailto:<email>?query`

If you want to start experimenting with developing crypto wallets I recommend learn first how a BTC Addresses and Transactions is created from scratch. After you can implement it to any programming language:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-generate-a-bitcoin-address-step-by-step-9d7fcbf1ad0b